# Winforms Report Viewer Control does not persist datepicker parameters after preview when running under Windows 10

Tags: winforms, reporting-services, datepicker, windows-10, reportviewer

After selecting the datepicker range from the parameters section at the top of the report, when View Report button is pressed, the parameters are blanked and do not reinstate.
This is particularly and issue with dynamic parameters as populating any parameter will alway blank date parameters preventing the report being executed.
I have tried all versions of the Report Viewer control that i can find and it always occurs. Always reproduable on all our SSRS reports when running in winforms control. I have also tried all versions of visual studio.
I have attached a gif animation of the issue.
The first part shows the error on windows 10, then i run the same program under Windows Server 2012 and it works fine.
[image: The first part shows the error on windows 10, then i run the same program under Windows Server 2012 and it works fine]

Comment: Are the locale and date format settings identical on the two PC's?

Comment: Correct. Both identical

Comment: Someone else MUST be seeing this issue or are we the only ones using this control?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not like all date formats, try another format and maybe it will function.
For me, the YYYY-MM-DD format also does not work in Windows 10
In the past, about a month ago, it did work, today when I tried a new report, does not work.

Comment: Can you provide any constructive information. For instance any source you found that explains _why_ this happens?

Comment: Well i cant see how that can change between windows versions. Im sure this is a bug but i can see no sign of it on the internet. Changing our date format is not an option as most of the world use DD/MM/YYYY and this has worked for us in this context until Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

OK so i made a monkey patch and here it is.
For others out there that are having trouble.

It was an interesting problem to solve as the windows that comprise the report viewer controls get destroyed each time the section refreshes so I needed to build a path to each control to reinsert the destroyed value.

I don't claim it works so don't ask me to fix anything. 
Purely as is where is.

use like

```
    private void reportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        W10ReportViewerMonkeyPatcher.Patch(reportViewer1);
    }
```

Module Begin

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;

//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch read it an weep
//Author: Justin Romaine
namespace MonkeyPatches
{

    public static class W10ReportViewerMonkeyPatcher
    {
        public static void Patch(Control reportControl)
        {

            if (!Win32.IsWindows10OrGreater())
                return;

            SubclassPatcher.reportViewerHandle = reportControl.Handle;
            var reportViewerControlWindows = Win32.EnumerateChildWindowHandles(reportControl.Handle);
            foreach (var a in reportViewerControlWindows)
            {
                SubclassPatcher.Attach(a);
            }
        }
        public static void Depatch()
        {
            SubclassPatcher.instancePaths.Clear();
            SubclassPatcher.reportViewerHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }

    public class SubclassPatcher : NativeWindow
    {


        public static IntPtr reportViewerHandle;
        public static Dictionary<string, SubclassPatcher> instancePaths = new Dictionary<string, SubclassPatcher>();
        static string MakeWindowPath(IntPtr handle)
        {
            var parent = handle;
            var s = "";
            do
            {

                s = Win32.GetClassName(parent) + "/" + s;
                var control = Control.FromHandle(parent);
                if (control != null && control.Name != "")
                    s = control.Name + "/" + s;
                if (control != null)
                {
                    s = control.GetType().FullName + "/" + s;
                    //important! this window changes position on first use. Removing the number from the path creates makes sure its unique between teardowns.
                    if (control.GetType().FullName == "Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.RSParams")
                        continue;
                }
                int pos = 0;
                var children = Win32.EnumerateChildWindowHandles(Win32.GetParent(parent));
                foreach (var child in children)
                {
                    if (Win32.GetParent(child) == parent)
                        pos++;
                }
                s = "(" + pos + ")/" + s;


            } while ((parent = Win32.GetParent(parent)) != reportViewerHandle);
            return s;
        }
        public string Path;
        public static SubclassPatcher Attach(IntPtr handle)
        {
            SubclassPatcher sub;
            var path = MakeWindowPath(handle);
            if (instancePaths.ContainsKey(path))
                sub = instancePaths[path];
            else
            {
                sub = new SubclassPatcher();
                instancePaths.Add(path, sub);
            }

            sub.ReleaseHandle();
            sub.AssignHandle(handle);
            sub.Path = path;
            return sub;
        }
        string savedValue;
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch ((Win32.WM)m.Msg)
            {
                case Win32.WM.WM_GETTEXT:
                    savedValue = Win32.GetWindowText(m.HWnd);
                    break;
                case Win32.WM.WM_PARENTNOTIFY:
                    if ((Win32.WM)m.WParam.Low16() == Win32.WM.WM_CREATE)
                    {
                        var control = Control.FromHandle(m.LParam);
                        var sub = SubclassPatcher.Attach(m.LParam);
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sub.savedValue))
                        {
                            Win32.SetWindowText(m.LParam, sub.savedValue);
                        }

                    }
                    break;
                case Win32.WM.WM_SETTEXT:
                    {
                        var hWndGreatGrandParent = Win32.GetParent(Win32.GetParent(Win32.GetParent(m.HWnd)));

                        if (hWndGreatGrandParent != null)
                        {
                            var control = Control.FromHandle(hWndGreatGrandParent);
                            if (control != null)
                                if (control.GetType().FullName.Contains("DateControl"))
                                {
                                    var s = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(m.LParam, 2000);
                                    savedValue = s;
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

    }
    public static class Extentions
    {
        public static int Low16(this IntPtr value)
        {
            return unchecked((short)(uint)value);   // classic unchecked cast to uint
        }
        public static int High16(this IntPtr value)
        {
            return unchecked((short)((uint)value >> 16));
        }

    }
    public static class Win32
    {
        public delegate bool EnumChildrenDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);
        public delegate bool EnumThreadDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetParent")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr child);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern uint SendMessage(
            IntPtr hWnd,
            WM Msg,              // Use WM_GETTEXT
            int wparam,
            int lparam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern uint SendMessage(
            IntPtr hWnd,
            WM Msg,              // Use WM_GETTEXT
            int countOfChars,
            StringBuilder text);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern uint SendMessage(
            IntPtr hWnd,
            WM Msg,              // Use WM_GETTEXT
            int wParam,
            string text);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(
            IntPtr hWndParent,
            EnumChildrenDelegate lpEnumFunc,
            IntPtr lParam);


        public static IEnumerable<IntPtr> EnumerateChildWindowHandles(IntPtr parent)
        {
            var handles = new List<IntPtr>();

            EnumChildWindows(parent,
                (hWnd, lParam) =>
                {
                    handles.Add(hWnd); return true;
                }, IntPtr.Zero);

            return handles;
        }
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool VerifyVersionInfo([In] ref OSVERSIONINFOEX lpVersionInfo,
           uint dwTypeMask, ulong dwlConditionMask);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct OSVERSIONINFOEX
        {
            public uint dwOSVersionInfoSize;
            public uint dwMajorVersion;
            public uint dwMinorVersion;
            public uint dwBuildNumber;
            public uint dwPlatformId;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)] public string szCSDVersion;
            public UInt16 wServicePackMajor;
            public UInt16 wServicePackMinor;
            public UInt16 wSuiteMask;
            public byte wProductType;
            public byte wReserved;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        extern static long VerSetConditionMask(
            [In] long ConditionMask,
            [In] uint TypeMask,
            [In] byte Condition);

        public static bool IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(uint wMajorVersion, uint wMinorVersion, UInt16 wServicePackMajor)
        {
            OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi = default (OSVERSIONINFOEX);
            osvi = new OSVERSIONINFOEX {
                dwOSVersionInfoSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(osvi),
                dwMajorVersion = 0,
                dwMinorVersion=0,
                dwBuildNumber= 0,
                dwPlatformId=0,
                szCSDVersion = "",
                wServicePackMajor = 0,
                wServicePackMinor= 0
            };
            long dwlConditionMask = VerSetConditionMask(VerSetConditionMask(VerSetConditionMask(0, 2, 3),1, 3),0x20, 3);

            osvi.dwMajorVersion = wMajorVersion;
            osvi.dwMinorVersion = wMinorVersion;
            osvi.wServicePackMajor = wServicePackMajor;

            return VerifyVersionInfo(ref osvi, 2 | 1 | 0x20, (ulong)dwlConditionMask) != false;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

        public static string GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder(2000);
            GetClassName(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static string GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder(2000);
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM.WM_GETTEXT, sb.Capacity, sb);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        public static void SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string text)
        {
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM.WM_SETTEXT, 0, text);
        }


        public static bool IsWindows10OrGreater()
        {
            return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(10, 0, 0);
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum WM
        {
            WM_NULL = 0x0000,
            WM_CREATE = 0x0001,
            WM_DESTROY = 0x0002,
            WM_MOVE = 0x0003,
            WM_SIZE = 0x0005,
            WM_ACTIVATE = 0x0006,
            WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007,
            WM_KILLFOCUS = 0x0008,
            WM_ENABLE = 0x000A,
            WM_SETREDRAW = 0x000B,
            WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C,
            WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D,
            WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E,
            WM_PAINT = 0x000F,
            WM_CLOSE = 0x0010,
            WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x0011,
            WM_QUERYOPEN = 0x0013,
            WM_ENDSESSION = 0x0016,
            WM_QUIT = 0x0012,
            WM_ERASEBKGND = 0x0014,
            WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE = 0x0015,
            WM_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0018,
            WM_WININICHANGE = 0x001A,
            WM_SETTINGCHANGE = WM_WININICHANGE,
            WM_DEVMODECHANGE = 0x001B,
            WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C,
            WM_FONTCHANGE = 0x001D,
            WM_TIMECHANGE = 0x001E,
            WM_CANCELMODE = 0x001F,
            WM_SETCURSOR = 0x0020,
            WM_MOUSEACTIVATE = 0x0021,
            WM_CHILDACTIVATE = 0x0022,
            WM_QUEUESYNC = 0x0023,
            WM_GETMINMAXINFO = 0x0024,
            WM_PAINTICON = 0x0026,
            WM_ICONERASEBKGND = 0x0027,
            WM_NEXTDLGCTL = 0x0028,
            WM_SPOOLERSTATUS = 0x002A,
            WM_DRAWITEM = 0x002B,
            WM_MEASUREITEM = 0x002C,
            WM_DELETEITEM = 0x002D,
            WM_VKEYTOITEM = 0x002E,
            WM_CHARTOITEM = 0x002F,
            WM_SETFONT = 0x0030,
            WM_GETFONT = 0x0031,
            WM_SETHOTKEY = 0x0032,
            WM_GETHOTKEY = 0x0033,
            WM_QUERYDRAGICON = 0x0037,
            WM_COMPAREITEM = 0x0039,
            WM_GETOBJECT = 0x003D,
            WM_COMPACTING = 0x0041,
            WM_COMMNOTIFY = 0x0044,
            WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x0046,
            WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED = 0x0047,
            WM_POWER = 0x0048,
            WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A,
            WM_CANCELJOURNAL = 0x004B,
            WM_NOTIFY = 0x004E,
            WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST = 0x0050,
            WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE = 0x0051,
            WM_TCARD = 0x0052,
            WM_HELP = 0x0053,
            WM_USERCHANGED = 0x0054,
            WM_NOTIFYFORMAT = 0x0055,
            WM_CONTEXTMENU = 0x007B,
            WM_STYLECHANGING = 0x007C,
            WM_STYLECHANGED = 0x007D,
            WM_DISPLAYCHANGE = 0x007E,
            WM_GETICON = 0x007F,
            WM_SETICON = 0x0080,
            WM_NCCREATE = 0x0081,
            WM_NCDESTROY = 0x0082,
            WM_NCCALCSIZE = 0x0083,
            WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084,
            WM_NCPAINT = 0x0085,
            WM_NCACTIVATE = 0x0086,
            WM_GETDLGCODE = 0x0087,
            WM_SYNCPAINT = 0x0088,


            WM_NCMOUSEMOVE = 0x00A0,
            WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A1,
            WM_NCLBUTTONUP = 0x00A2,
            WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A3,
            WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A4,
            WM_NCRBUTTONUP = 0x00A5,
            WM_NCRBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A6,
            WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A7,
            WM_NCMBUTTONUP = 0x00A8,
            WM_NCMBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A9,
            WM_NCXBUTTONDOWN = 0x00AB,
            WM_NCXBUTTONUP = 0x00AC,
            WM_NCXBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00AD,

            WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE = 0x00FE,
            WM_INPUT = 0x00FF,

            WM_KEYFIRST = 0x0100,
            WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100,
            WM_KEYUP = 0x0101,
            WM_CHAR = 0x0102,
            WM_DEADCHAR = 0x0103,
            WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104,
            WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x0105,
            WM_SYSCHAR = 0x0106,
            WM_SYSDEADCHAR = 0x0107,
            WM_UNICHAR = 0x0109,
            WM_KEYLAST = 0x0109,

            WM_IME_STARTCOMPOSITION = 0x010D,
            WM_IME_ENDCOMPOSITION = 0x010E,
            WM_IME_COMPOSITION = 0x010F,
            WM_IME_KEYLAST = 0x010F,

            WM_INITDIALOG = 0x0110,
            WM_COMMAND = 0x0111,
            WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112,
            WM_TIMER = 0x0113,
            WM_HSCROLL = 0x0114,
            WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115,
            WM_INITMENU = 0x0116,
            WM_INITMENUPOPUP = 0x0117,
            WM_MENUSELECT = 0x011F,
            WM_MENUCHAR = 0x0120,
            WM_ENTERIDLE = 0x0121,
            WM_MENURBUTTONUP = 0x0122,
            WM_MENUDRAG = 0x0123,
            WM_MENUGETOBJECT = 0x0124,
            WM_UNINITMENUPOPUP = 0x0125,
            WM_MENUCOMMAND = 0x0126,

            WM_CHANGEUISTATE = 0x0127,
            WM_UPDATEUISTATE = 0x0128,
            WM_QUERYUISTATE = 0x0129,

            WM_CTLCOLORMSGBOX = 0x0132,
            WM_CTLCOLOREDIT = 0x0133,
            WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX = 0x0134,
            WM_CTLCOLORBTN = 0x0135,
            WM_CTLCOLORDLG = 0x0136,
            WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR = 0x0137,
            WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC = 0x0138,
            MN_GETHMENU = 0x01E1,

            WM_MOUSEFIRST = 0x0200,
            WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
            WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
            WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203,
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
            WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205,
            WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0206,
            WM_MBUTTONDOWN = 0x0207,
            WM_MBUTTONUP = 0x0208,
            WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0209,
            WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
            WM_XBUTTONDOWN = 0x020B,
            WM_XBUTTONUP = 0x020C,
            WM_XBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x020D,
            WM_MOUSEHWHEEL = 0x020E,

            WM_PARENTNOTIFY = 0x0210,
            WM_ENTERMENULOOP = 0x0211,
            WM_EXITMENULOOP = 0x0212,

            WM_NEXTMENU = 0x0213,
            WM_SIZING = 0x0214,
            WM_CAPTURECHANGED = 0x0215,
            WM_MOVING = 0x0216,

            WM_POWERBROADCAST = 0x0218,

            WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219,

            WM_MDICREATE = 0x0220,
            WM_MDIDESTROY = 0x0221,
            WM_MDIACTIVATE = 0x0222,
            WM_MDIRESTORE = 0x0223,
            WM_MDINEXT = 0x0224,
            WM_MDIMAXIMIZE = 0x0225,
            WM_MDITILE = 0x0226,
            WM_MDICASCADE = 0x0227,
            WM_MDIICONARRANGE = 0x0228,
            WM_MDIGETACTIVE = 0x0229,


            WM_MDISETMENU = 0x0230,
            WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE = 0x0231,
            WM_EXITSIZEMOVE = 0x0232,
            WM_DROPFILES = 0x0233,
            WM_MDIREFRESHMENU = 0x0234,

            WM_IME_SETCONTEXT = 0x0281,
            WM_IME_NOTIFY = 0x0282,
            WM_IME_CONTROL = 0x0283,
            WM_IME_COMPOSITIONFULL = 0x0284,
            WM_IME_SELECT = 0x0285,
            WM_IME_CHAR = 0x0286,
            WM_IME_REQUEST = 0x0288,
            WM_IME_KEYDOWN = 0x0290,
            WM_IME_KEYUP = 0x0291,

            WM_MOUSEHOVER = 0x02A1,
            WM_MOUSELEAVE = 0x02A3,
            WM_NCMOUSEHOVER = 0x02A0,
            WM_NCMOUSELEAVE = 0x02A2,

            WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE = 0x02B1,

            WM_TABLET_FIRST = 0x02c0,
            WM_TABLET_LAST = 0x02df,

            WM_CUT = 0x0300,
            WM_COPY = 0x0301,
            WM_PASTE = 0x0302,
            WM_CLEAR = 0x0303,
            WM_UNDO = 0x0304,
            WM_RENDERFORMAT = 0x0305,
            WM_RENDERALLFORMATS = 0x0306,
            WM_DESTROYCLIPBOARD = 0x0307,
            WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x0308,
            WM_PAINTCLIPBOARD = 0x0309,
            WM_VSCROLLCLIPBOARD = 0x030A,
            WM_SIZECLIPBOARD = 0x030B,
            WM_ASKCBFORMATNAME = 0x030C,
            WM_CHANGECBCHAIN = 0x030D,
            WM_HSCROLLCLIPBOARD = 0x030E,
            WM_QUERYNEWPALETTE = 0x030F,
            WM_PALETTEISCHANGING = 0x0310,
            WM_PALETTECHANGED = 0x0311,
            WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312,

            WM_PRINT = 0x0317,
            WM_PRINTCLIENT = 0x0318,

            WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x0319,

            WM_THEMECHANGED = 0x031A,

            WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE = 0x031D,

            WM_DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED = 0x031E,
            WM_DWMNCRENDERINGCHANGED = 0x031F,
            WM_DWMCOLORIZATIONCOLORCHANGED = 0x0320,
            WM_DWMWINDOWMAXIMIZEDCHANGE = 0x0321,

            WM_GETTITLEBARINFOEX = 0x033F,

            WM_HANDHELDFIRST = 0x0358,
            WM_HANDHELDLAST = 0x035F,

            WM_AFXFIRST = 0x0360,
            WM_AFXLAST = 0x037F,

            WM_PENWINFIRST = 0x0380,
            WM_PENWINLAST = 0x038F,

            WM_APP = 0x8000,

            WM_USER = 0x0400,

            WM_REFLECT = WM_USER + 0x1C00,
            EM_GETSEL = 0x00B0,
            EM_SETSEL = 0x00B1

        }

    }
}
```